# How does adblock regex work?

Tags: regex, adblock

[Here](http://adblockplus.org/en/filters) I found adblock regex explanation. I wish to block all images containing "bbelements" in their url, but neither "**bbelements**" nor "****bbelements****" worked for me.
Surely it must be something very trivial, but I can't figure it out. So how to hide images with bbelements in their url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this user even exists anymore, but I still wanted to answer the Q.

Adblock outlines how it works [in the FAQ here](http://adblockplus.org/en/faq_internal#elemhide) and [then deep dives into code here](http://adblockplus.org/blog/investigating-filter-matching-algorithms).

Phew, I feel better now that this Q is A-ed.

Comment: Re "I don't think this user even exists anymore": It might have *never* existed here; the question was originally posted on StackOverflow.

Comment: It's a good answer though, so feel free to check it if you have god powers on here :)

Comment: Well, I do exist.